# How do I exclude a page from an htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a htaccess maintenance redirect,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

It works - but how do I exclude a page from the redirect so I can access that page in order to see what's going on during maintenance?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use regex alternation to add more pasge in your rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(maintenance\.php|page\.php)$
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Now `page.php` will be excluded from this rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your IP address for which redirection will not occur, see example below. Replace `AA.BB.CC.DD` with your actual IP address.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=AA.BB.CC.DD
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```